# File path for css background images

Tags: css

I am working on a  local project at the minute, I am using some background CSS images the file route is

```
/Volumes/Macintosh HD/Users/William/Desktop/websites/webtest/images/plane.png
```

if i change the route to /webtest/images/plane.png will the person receiving see the images if I copy this whole project into a zipped up file with that route?

Sorry this is a NOOB question.

Comment: Use relative paths ... not absolute

Comment: and copy the files somewhere into your project

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It also depends how your website is structured. Assuming that your project looks like this, the paths of your images should be relative to the folder:

```
website
   webtest
     images
       plane.png
      css
       style.css
```

Your paths in style.css should look like:

```
.class {
    background: url('../images/plane.png') 0 0 no-repeat;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

No, the recieving person will probably have problems, I think.

It'll be better to use `./images/plane.png` or only `images/plane.png` if the page is something like `/Volumes/Macintosh HD/Users/William/Desktop/websites/webtest/index.php`
because `/` will access the root of the current IP-address or domain. It also depends on the css files location if you're using one.

Hope it helps ;)